# Bluetooth not working on Xubuntu 12.04.03 (WiFi/Bt combo: qcwb335)

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

Since WiFi wasn't working at all with my fresh 12.04, I ran the following to solve the not working WiFi:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.8-precise-generic
```

The problem is Blueman Device Manager 1.23 is not discovering any Bt device.
[Here there is a description of the same problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1237296).

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the question. Bluetooth problem or Wifi?

For bluetooth try

`sudo apt-get install bluez-gnome bluetooth gnome-bluetooth`

and then `(sleep 5s && bluetooth-applet) &`

For wifi, Use ethernet, connect your PC to the router via a cable, then go to settings manager -> additional drivers -> install whatever Wifi driver you see, not the default one :)

Comment: The problem is Bluetooth, tried your advice, but get an error.      Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package bluez-gnome is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bluez-gnome' has no installation candidate

Comment: I installed the gnome-bluetooth, but the BT devices were not discovered. I think it must be something with WiFi/Bt combo: qcwb335 driver of firmware

Comment: @jamiro007 are you sure that you tick "make device visible"? also how about make your PC visible and then go to your mobile try to connect to it? also go to ubuntu software center and install a package called "bluetooth support"

Comment: installed bluetooth support, but no device visible.I checked that the BT Adapter is Always visible -> xubuntu-0. I can see the BT Speaker with my Nexus5 Device, no problem. I still think it must be something with the atheros driver.

Comment: @jamiro007 would you consider trying 13.10? newer ubuntu version may have fixed this bug

Comment: @Fisher at the moment I'm running on Xubuntu 12.04.03 and not planning to update. Do yo think  if i go virtual with aqemu + 13.10 the BT driver will work?

Comment: @jamiro007 To be honest, I don't know, try it